Show aggregated values breakdown in a separate column?
I wanted to ask how can i see which values have been aggregated during the aggregation when using for example a sum agg in SQL.
E.G



Product
Quan




A
5


A
10



Consider this i want to agg the Quan and to breakdown the values used.
Result should look lke this:



Product
Agg_Quan
Details




A
15
5, 10



Currently i have this abap class executing some select query.
I want to find a way either by directly executing a cds view or with an abap class.
CLASS zcl_flights_demo_cds IMPLEMENTATION.
METHOD flights_connections
    BY DATABASE FUNCTION
    FOR HDB
    LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
    OPTIONS READ-ONLY
    USING ZWODPROBLEM.

        itab_cities =
            SELECT
                ZWODPROBLEM.mandt as client,
                ZWODPROBLEM.product as airline_code,
                CAST(ZWODPROBLEM.phyquan AS INT) as total_phyquan,
                ZWODPROBLEM.Origin2 as city_to,
                SUM(ZWODPROBLEM.phyquan) OVER (PARTITION BY ZWODPROBLEM.product) as total_phyquan_agg
            FROM ZWODPROBLEM;

       RETURN
            SELECT client,
                    airline_code,
                    total_phyquan_agg as total_phyquan,
                    STRING_AGG(CONCAT(city_to, CONCAT('-', total_phyquan)), ', ') as cities_to
             FROM :itab_cities
             GROUP BY client, airline_code, total_phyquan_agg, city_to, total_phyquan;
ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.
Thanks!

STRING_AGG function should take care of concatenating all the summed up values and show in Details column. Not clear what your question is. If you are looking to execute native HANA functionality from CDS views.. there is CDS table functions available

Other option is to select the data from DB table and do the manipulation inside loop at ITAB. There are many ways you can achieve it. Is tat what you are looking?

Hello thanks, yes i simply want to see the single values which have been aggregated during the SUM aggregation. As you see in the result 10 and 5 gets added to 15. I thought of table functions but i am not quite sure.

Ah i solved it.
> METHOD flights_connections
>         BY DATABASE FUNCTION
>         FOR HDB
>         LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
>         OPTIONS READ-ONLY
>         USING ZWODPROBLEM.
> 
>             itab_coo =
>                 SELECT
>                     ZWODPROBLEM.mandt as client,
>                     ZWODPROBLEM.docNr as docNr,
>                     ZWODPROBLEM.Country_of_Origin as restriction,
>                     cast(ZWODPROBLEM.quantity as INT) as ODQuantity,
>                     ZWODPROBLEM.product as airline_code,
>                     sum(ZWODPROBLEM.phyquan) as total_phyquan,
>                     STRING_AGG(concat(ZWODPROBLEM.coo_item, concat('-',cast(ZWODPROBLEM.phyquan as INT))), ', ') as city_to
>                 FROM ZWODPROBLEM
>                 GROUP BY ZWODPROBLEM.mandt,ZWODPROBLEM.docNr,ZWODPROBLEM.Country_of_Origin,ZWODPROBLEM.quantity,ZWODPROBLEM.product;
>            RETURN
>                 SELECT client,
>                         docNr,
>                         restriction,
>                         ODQuantity,
>                         airline_code,
>                         total_phyquan as total_phyquan,
>                         city_to as cities_to
>                  FROM :itab_coo
>                  GROUP BY client,airline_code,restriction, ODQuantity, docNr,total_phyquan,city_to;
>     ENDMETHOD.

Now i get the aggregated values separated by its origin in one column:
Total Quantity ---- Summed
200 ---- -50, TR-2, TR-2, TR-3, TR-3, TR-85, IT-10, AT-10, -23, -2, -10
